# How to know if react-native-git-upgrade was successful?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a bit confused by `react-native-git-upgrade` process flow, It seems to work fine, but it only updates packages in package.json, never native files in android or ios. These files are changed in my project i.e. changed app bundle id's, icons, launch screens etc... I am wondering if this is why it never updates them?

Also, what in release notes can indicate that something changed in native files, so we can use it as confirmation maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the documentation it says is automatic.

> IMPORTANT: You don't have to install the new version of the
>   react-native package, it will be installed automatically.
>   Blockquote

But in case of any doubt you can always delete the ios and android folder, and do the following:

```
react-native eject
```

This command is gonna create the ios and android projects.

You should follow the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html):
But if the above doesn't work to update, then is a different problem and I suggest to create an issue.